# How to change the colour fill the cell based in the drop list menu?

Tags: excel-2016

I have found out how to get the last occurrence of the selected name from a list in excel 2016. The problem is that I want to "highlight" or change the color fill of the cell that is in the criteria when I choose its name in the list.

This is my code:

```
=PROC(2;1/(C1:C199=P61);A1:A199)
```

In my spreadsheet the name is in the 'C' column and the data is in the A column.

What I need is only to know how to change the color like in the image below. The drop list name and data code I know how to do.

[image]

Link of the image: [enter link description here](https://trumpexcel.com/find-the-last-occurrence-of-an-item-in-a-list-in-excel/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by applying a `Conditional Formatting` to the desired range.

Make sure to select `Range("A2:B15")`, and then go to:

```
Home > Conditional Formatting > New rule > Use a Formula to determine which cells to format
```

Write this formula, and choose a format:

```
=COUNTIFS($A2;$D$3;$B2;$E$3)>0
```

Click `OK`, and then `Apply`

Comment: It doesn't work. I was trying to use something like =(A2:A15=D3)AND(B2:B15=E3) in the new rule formula but without any progress. I'm very bad with excel.

Comment: It does work. Depending on your computer locale you may have to replace ';' with a ',' but it works. Also make sure to have the Range selected before applying the formatting, and respect the '$' signs! If you don't use them of course it won't work.